# Chaining commands to use ls to recursively list files modified in last 24 hours?

Tags: unix, command-line

Can someone help me with chaining commands to use `ls` to recursively list all files modified in last 24 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `ls`, use `find`:

```
find . -mtime -1
```